# Check if cookie exists based on part of its name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I want to check if a cookie exists based on the first couple characters in the name.

For example I have a cookie like

data_323242=1

How can I check to see if a cookie with "data" as a prefix exists using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check if exists:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
var isDataCookies = cookies.some(function(cookie){
    if (cookie.replace(/\s/, '').indexOf('data') === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then check if `isDataCookies` is true or false.

Or you can use the same function with filter, and then get an array with all cookies prefixed with data, and then handle it as you want:

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
var dataCookies = cookies.filter(function(cookie){
    if (cookie.replace(/\s/, '').indexOf('data') === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

`dataCookies` will be an array containing all cookies that matches 'datawhatever'.